# Web site is not able to open at IIS7 in client but not in local iis 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

i am facing one problem from the last 25 days onwards ..

Ie.  i publish  one web site it is having 30  forms  local source code working all forms 
local server IIS7  working fine  like source code

But the problem is at client server i.e also  IIS7  out of  30 forms 3  forms are i am not able to open after press the menu 
It is showing `content controls are not allowed  inside the tag`..some error message.. three forms are showing the same message..

May i know what should i do..
Some body  suggested  some problem in coding tags ..i don't know how to solve the problem..

but i had observed
3 days on words strange thing was  happens

while building  also  error is comming

plz have a look on below link
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/471108/Error-JPG.html
it is showing three erros
i said three forms are not  able to open that 3 forms are showing errors

if i open the error contained design page

http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/471109/Error1-JPG.html

after doing some changes in  Source code 
Removing last   tag again again build it
I can build it successfully but in client server..it has the same problem.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: this is my design code in this form  i am getting the problm http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/471112/leave-txt.html

Comment: Can you post your source code of the file that you have problems in?

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/471173/Leaverequest-txt.html hi above  i given  one link leave-txt ie. design code  and  here i mentioning this is  vb.net code..can u plz check it what was wrong in my code sorry for the late reply..